# Google-Apps-Script can not write back a database with getDataRange().setValues()

Tags: google-apps-script, arrayofarrays

I have a database loaded from a google spreadsheet:

`mydatabase = sheet.getDataRange().getValues()`

which then I extend with a new record:

`mydatabase.push(mydatabase[x])`

and then at the end of the script, I would want to write back the entire database to the google spreadsheet but the

`sheet.getDataRange().setValues(mydatabase)`

gives me ERROR since the new database is one record higher than the original was when loaded.

Is there any way to force the getDataRange() to write back the database into the sheet? The spreadsheet otherwise would have enough rows to accommodate the bigger dataset.

Comment: You cannot use getDataRange when writing back the array, instead just define the range using getRange(1,1,array.length,array[0].length)  if your array is homogeneous then it will work.

Comment: well ... with all my honesty I tried this version too during my solution searching but it didnt want to go through either ... it gave me the error of >>Cannot find method getRange(number,number,number,number)<< and seemed to me it insists on a1notation is required ...

Comment: It doesn't. This method is valid. Is the added data structure exactly the same as the existing one? I mean same row length.

Comment: OK ... it works now ... but help me please understanding what I was trying for so long wrong:: when I was loading the database from the 'as   = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()' I wasnt able to use your suggested solution ... but when I added the 'ss   = as.getSheetByName("Sheet1")' and the database was loaded from ss.getDataRange()... than I was able to use the ss.getRange(1,1,length,length) and didnt get that stupid error message.

Comment: If I understand correctly, as is the spreadsheet and ss is the sheet are you sure you didn't make a confusion between those two? It would explain the error message you were getting.

Comment: thank you @Sergeinsas! That was making the error!

Comment: Cool, glad to hear :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, for `.setValues(obj[][])` to work as expected, the `Range` that it is acting on must be the same size as the `obj[][]`.

Commonly, this is ensured by acquiring a new `Range` from the desired `Sheet`:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("some id");
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("some name");
var db = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
/*
 * Do some operations on the obj[][] that is db
 * these operations can include adding / removing rows or columns.
 */
// If db is smaller than existing "written" data, the existing data should be cleared first.
if(db.length < sheet.getLastRow() || db[0].length < sheet.getLastColumn())
  sheet.clearContent();
// Write the current db back to the sheet, after acquiring the
// exact number of rows and columns needed to hold the values.
sheet.getRange(1, 1, db.length, db[0].length).setValues(db);
```